# How to get a list of middlewares in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

How do I get a list of active middlewares?
How do I get a list of middlewares for specific url (each url may have a different set of middlewares added to the pipeline)?

I would like to know which middlewares are being added by using some of the common builder extensions like `UseMvc()` or `app.UseIdentity();`

I know I could check the source code of each extension. Is there a runtime method to get this?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. When you add a middleware to the pipeline, it's resolved to a `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>`. The *components* are saved in a private field in the [`ApplicationBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/ApplicationBuilder.cs#L14) implementation. You could however bake an extension method with some reflection magic to determine the actual middleware type, but it's not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a list of middlewares in Stack.
You can add your middleware last, put a breakpoint somewhere in the Invoke method. When debugger will stop, you will see all previous calls to other middlewares.

Answer (score 1):

To add on another answer, in .NET 6.0, I got it with the debugger: in `Program.cs` put a breakpoint in `app.Run()`, which executes once the pipeline has been set (refer to all those `app.UseMyMiddlewareName()` statements). Then, inspect the `app` variable and follow this path:

`app > Non-Public members > ApplicationBuilder > Non-Publi members > _components`

There we have the list of middlewares. For each item in the list, follow:

`[<itemIndex>] > Target > middleware`

Just a curious note: as we now, the order in which we specifiy the middlewares in the code matters. If we change that order, the list in the debugger will reflect it accordingly.

[image]