# How can I get a list of registered middleware in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

In ASP.NET Core, you can register new middleware into the request processing pipeline during the `Configure` method of the startup class you're using for your web host builder by using `app.UseMiddleware(...)`.  During debugging, how do I get a list of registered middleware providers, though?  I can't see any way to actually view the middleware that's been registered for the app.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234762/how-to-get-a-list-of-middlewares-in-asp-net-core

Comment: What is your exact scenario? Do you have write access to the application's source code, to be able to add functionality/extension methods?

Comment: @JanWichelmann Well it's my application that's using ASP.NET Core, if that's what you mean.  I can obviously change my source code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From another question that someone's pointed out is very similar to this one:

The list of middleware is not publically available, for some reason.  In debug mode, though, it is available by examining the `IApplicationBuilder app` variable during execution of the `Configure` method, specifically the `_components` non-public member.  This non-public member is an `IList<Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>>`, containing a list of entries representing the middlewares that have been registered so far.

Answer (score 10):

Though question is to get middleware list during debugging, just in case someone needs, following reflection based code can be used to get list of registered middleware in request pipeline programmatically:

```
private void CollectListOfMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    _listOfMiddleware = new StringBuilder();
    FieldInfo _componentsField = app.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "_components");
    List<Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>> _componentsValue =
        _componentsField.GetValue(app) as List<Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>>;
    _componentsValue.ForEach(x =>
    {
        FieldInfo middlewareField = x.Target.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().Single(pi => pi.Name == "middleware");
        object middlewareValue = middlewareField.GetValue(x.Target);
        _listOfMiddleware.Append($"{middlewareValue.ToString()}\n");
    }
    );
}
```